# Can I force the `firefox` command line application not to switch the active tab in my open browser?

Tags: command-line, firefox, command-line-arguments

When I use the `firefox` command from command line (even with the `--new-tab` switch) Firefox swithes to the newly opened tab... I don't want this, can I set the default

About configs:

- `browser.tabs.loadInBackground` is set to `true`

So when I open a new tab, it does not switch focus... only when I use it from the command line...

How can I make the behavior to not to imply switching to the newly opened tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course... after I submit a question I just find the answer by accident...

Tried changing the `browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground` parameter on `about:config` to `true`. This seems to work.